# R must be atomic for 'sort.list'

Tags: r

R newbie here. I am having difficulty understanding what is wrong here.

Why does

```
mylistx[sort.list(mylistx)]
```

> return R must be atomic for **'sort.list'.**
>   Have you called 'sort' on a list?

```
str(mylistx)   
 $ a: num 1
 $ b: num 3
 $ c: num 2
 $ d: num 0
```

my desired output for this is:

```
 $ d: num 0
 $ a: num 1
 $ c: num 2
 $ b: num 3
```

Thanks.

Comment: For your example I would go with `mylistx[order(unlist(mylistx))]`

Comment: The problem is that you are using a list as a vector. A list can contain elements of different types and sizes and then it becomes difficult to know how to sort. How do you sort `(1,2), 2, (2,1)`? What you can do, however is convert it to a vector and then sort it. `sort(unlist(mylistx))`.

Comment: @Therkel got it. thank you!